# How to create random combination with certain rules

Tags: algorithm, sorting, random

This might be a bit of a math problem but I need to do it programatically and that is what I struggle with. So here is the problem:

- I have sport categories (each with arbitrary number of competitors) with times they start at (they may start at the same time or at different times arbitrarily). *I.e. Category A starts at 10:00, B at 10:00, C at 10:30 etc.*
- I need to randomly reorder each categories' competitors and then assign each competitor a start time in this new order in the interval of 5 minutes starting from the category start. *I.e. Competitor1 in category A at 10:00, Competitor2 in Category A at 10:05, Competitor1 in category B at 10:00, Competitor1 in category C at 10:30 etc.*
- Each competitor has a **country** and there is a rule that there must NOT be two competitors from the same country that start at the same time (regardless of category). If that would happen a person must switch places inside their category with someone else so that it does not happen.

I am struggling in creating an algorithm that would give me the solution if it exists AND would exit when there is no solution. So far I managed to randomly reorder the categories and give them start times. But when applying the rules to this result and reordering elements in various fashion I either get into the infinite loop or end up with errors in the result (two people from the same country starting at the same time).

Comment: It stinks of NP-complete problem, in its worst case (I am probably wrong, but I cannot imagine a valid greedy algorithm). So... do you mind using an heuristic (or a greedy with some tricks)? You get an infinite loop on easy and solvable problems, or on arbitrary ones? Why don't you share your pseudo-code?

Comment: @MariusSiuram I figured as much. :-/ Well I have two sets of arbitrary categories, one with equal length and second with various length. Normally I randomly shuffle each category separately and give competitors start times. Then I go through each category and check if the position of a competitor is valid. If not I search the rest of the category for valid spot and swap if possible. Doing it twice consecutively  yields only some errors for ~300 competitors and doing it 10 or 100 times is not much improvement. Maybe I am missing some better way...

Comment: You should try to start from the most difficult part. For example, start from the country with most competitors and assign different times to all those competitors. Or, start from the time of day when there is the largest degree of overlap between categories and fill those time slots with random competitors, rejecting any choice that leads to a conflict.